# Titanium - Event listener for annotation

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, appcelerator, event-listener

I am a beginner in Titanium Studio. I am opening a new window, when I select the annotation pin on the mapview.

```
annotation.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("Opening detail window");
    navGroup.open(detailWindow);
});
```

But, it doesn't work every time. It works only for the first time, when the annotation is performed.

How could I make it work, whenever I select the annotation pin, I should move to a new window? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is your navgroup? your info output appears every click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use annotation right button to open a new window.
To catch the annotation right button click event you have to do this:

```
var mapView.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        // if user click on rightButton of annotaion
        if ( evt.clicksource == 'rightButton' ) {
            Ti.API.info("Opening detail window");
            navGroup.open(detailWindow);
        }
});
```